# Converting Complex JSON to C# Model

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to resolve the some complex JSON I am receiving to convert it to a C# Model so I can analyse and manipulate the data. I have tried converting the JSON by using JSON to C# but it doesn't work well when the name is dynamic. I want to focus on the Data.

The Item1 and SubItem1 etc are all variable strings so I can't hard code a model to pull them and the text is just a string within. The issue I am having is how to get the JSON into a usable format to access the Item1, SubItem1 and text values to manipulate their data.

I have looked into Dictionaries as suggested elsewhere but I am having no luck.

Model I have tried

```
public class Data
{
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public ResultInfo ResultInfo { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, SubData> Data {get;set;}
}

public class SubData
{
   public Dictionary<string,List<string>> item {get;set;}
}
```

JSON

```
{
    "Status": "OK",
    "ResultInfo": {
        "Prev": "PageUPURL",
        "Next": "PageDownURL",
        "total_count": "37",
        "per_page": "3",
        "page": "1"
    },
    "Message": "Ok.",
    "Data": {
        "Item1": [
            {
                "SubItem1": [
                    "Text"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Item2": [
            {
                "SubItem2": [
                    "Text",
                    "Text",
                    "Text"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Item3": [
            {
                "SubItem3": [
                    "Text"
                ]
            },
            {
                "SubItem4": [
                    "Text"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Any suggestions, advice or help would be gratefully received.

Comment: I think you just missed one level `public Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>> Data { get; set; }` as `ItemX` is followed by `[` it's a list or array.

Comment: Change your Data to `public Dictionary<string, List<SubData>> Data {get;set;}`

Comment: for those you can use https://app.quicktype.io, and simply rename property name where you want to force dictionary to "1","2" . And voila.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I hate it so much one its one tiny thing you miss that causes the issue!

Comment: I think neither of us, try our suggestion. Because I don't have an IDE at hands. We may be wrong. So try it first ^^

Comment: Hi @Self, That solved it, it is now in a format I can extract data from Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those task I use https://app.quicktype.io .
Because it can easly reconnize dictionary when the property name are numeric you just need to edit your Json a little.
And past it into the tool.

```
{
    "Status": "OK",
    "ResultInfo": {
        "Prev": "PageUPURL",
        "Next": "PageDownURL",
        "total_count": "37",
        "per_page": "3",
        "page": "1"
    },
    "Message": "Ok.",
    "Data": {
        "1": [
            {
                "1": [
                    "Text"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "2": [
            {
                "1": [
                    "Text",
                    "Text",
                    "Text"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "3": [
            {
                "1": [
                    "Text"
                ]
            },
            {
                "2": [
                    "Text"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The result class is :

```
public partial class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ResultInfo")]
    public ResultInfo ResultInfo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Data")]
    public Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>> Data { get; set; }
}

public partial class ResultInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("Prev")]
    public string Prev { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Next")]
    public string Next { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("total_count")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public long TotalCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("per_page")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public long PerPage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("page")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public long Page { get; set; }
}
```

Online Demo  https://dotnetfiddle.net/1j42kR

---

nota bene: that tool also included a converter from "string" to "long" for `"per_page": "3",`

Answer (score 0):

Change below line

```cs
public Dictionary<string, SubData> Data {get;set;}
```

as

```cs
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string[]>[]> Data { get; set; }
```